# setup a relative layout with multiple icons

Tags: android, layout

I want to implement this layout and I don't know how. Without icons it's so simple but I don't know what to do with icons. The triangle icon does not show.

[image]

This is what I did:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:padding="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblmessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="برای ثبت نام شماره تلفن همراه خود را وارد کنید. همچینن کد تایید برای همین شماره پیامک می شود که در ادامه به آن نیاز دارید."
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Alert"
        android:src="@drawable/image9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblmessage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblmessage" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is your problem??

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: can u please attach your xml layout file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`drawableLeft`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) and [`drawableRight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) attributes to set icons in `EditText`.

And `layout_toLeftOf` to set your message `TextView` lef of the alert image.

eg:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:padding="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblmessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="برای ثبت نام شماره تلفن همراه خود را وارد کنید. همچینن کد تایید برای همین شماره پیامک می شود که در ادامه به آن نیاز دارید."
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Alert"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Alert"
            android:src="@drawable/image9"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/editTextLeftIcon"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/editTextRightIcon"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblmessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="برای ثبت نام شماره تلفن همراه خود را وارد کنید. همچینن کد تایید برای همین شماره پیامک می شود که در ادامه به آن نیاز دارید." />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/editTextLeftIcon"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/editTextRightIcon"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Alert"
            android:src="@drawable/image9"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Drawable parameters are awesome. But I want the message to be center horizontal.